# OnRow add event and update cell in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I would like to catch an event once a row is added to a google sheet (via google forms) using google script api , is it possible ?
My Spreadsheet has multiple sheets but i am only interested on the rows added to a specific sheet.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to find some information regarding your question [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Look into Form Submit event in the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

If you are using the built-in feature to send responses from a Google Form to a Google spreadsheet, use the on form submit event.

## Explanation

The [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) doesn't have event triggers, only Google Apps Script. By the other bear in mind that the installable trigger on change is triggered only by changes made by the "user on keyboard".

## References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events